# How to create twitter tab bar push animation

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiviewanimation, tabbar

I have the following code:

```
    private var bounceAnimation: CAKeyframeAnimation = {
        let bounceAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        bounceAnimation.values = [1.0, 1.4, 0.9, 1.02, 1.0]
        bounceAnimation.duration = TimeInterval(0.3)
        bounceAnimation.calculationMode = CAAnimationCalculationMode.cubic
        return bounceAnimation
    }()
```

This creates the animation where the icon gets bigger and then smaller. I am trying to create the animation where the icon gets smaller and then back to normal like it's being pushed similar to twitter, Spotify, etc. I assume it's just changing around the bounce values all though I'm not sure how would I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a normal `UIView.animate` function like this:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
}, completion: nil)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.05, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 7, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    view.transform = .identity
}, completion: nil)
```

Just change `view` to be whatever view you're trying to animate. Then mess around with the initial scale, the duration and the spring dampening to get the animation you want!

Comment: this works although this only animates the icon, how would I get it to animate the title also

Comment: @coder123 add the title label like `label.transform ...`

Comment: I added: `tabBarItem.title.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.35, y: 1.35)` by doing this I got the error: `Value of type 'String?' has no member 'transform'` what am I doing wrong